# Using Boolean to filter instead of a ternary operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am passing in a style prop as follows which works fine as follows where I draw gradient colors

 if $gradientProps is true.

**Working copy**

```
style={{
    backgroundImage: `url('${imageUrl}') ${
        $gradientProps
        ? `, linear-gradient(${
            $gradientProps.angle
            }, ${$gradientProps.colors.join()})`
        : ""
    }`
}}
```

But I am looking to NOT have to pass in that empty string when it is not available thus

going for the following. When I do this, I end up with an empty white space. Could I please
check what I am doing wrong pls? Thanks.

**What I am trying to do but end up with white background.**

```
style={{
    backgroundImage: [
        `url('${imageUrl}')`,
        $gradientProps &&
        `linear-gradient(${
            $gradientProps.angle
        }, ${$gradientProps.colors.join()})`
    ]
        .filter(Boolean)
        .join(" ")
}}
```

Comment: if you do not want the empty space, why do not you just remove the space after `url('${imageUrl}')`? Simply change from `url('${imageUrl}') ${$gradientProps ? ...` to `url('${imageUrl}')${$gradientProps ? ...`

Comment: @secan Thanks. That is my backup solution to this. But trying to see if I could do this without the ?mark and empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second parameter is `null` or `undefined`, you end up with a white background.

```js
style={{
    backgroundImage:!gradientProps ? `url('${imageUrl}')`:
        `url('${imageUrl}'),
        linear-gradient(${
            $gradientProps.angle
        }, ${$gradientProps.colors.join()})`
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, this still ends up with white background when $gradientProps is present. When not present, image shows up fine.

Comment: Hm is fine when I remove filter and join.

Comment: @karvai First `join` seperates with a `,`, but second `join("")` separates with a space, I believe in both you should use `join()`.

Comment: @karvai, i believe yes you can remove them. i updated the answer again.